# R downloading file from S3

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I need to download a file from an S3 bucket hosted by my company, so far I am able to retrieve data using the `paws` package:

```
library("aws.s3")
library("paws")
paws::s3(config = list(endpoint = "myendpoint"))
mycsv_raw <- s3$get_object(Bucket = "mybucket", key="myfile.csv")
mycsv <- rawToChar(mycsv_raw$Body)
write.csv(mycsv)
```

However, this is not good because I need to manually convert the raw file to a csv - and that might be more difficult for other types of files. Is there not a way to just download the file locally directly as a csv ?

When I try using `aws.s3` I get an error in `curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : could not resolve host xxxx` do you have any idea how to make that work? I am of course in a locked down corporate environment... But I am using the same endpoint in both cases so why does it work with one ane not the other?

```
Sys.setenv(
  AWS_S3_ENDPOINT = "https://xxxx"
)
test <- get_object(object = "myfile.csv", bucket = "mybucket", 
                   file = "mydownloadedfile.csv")
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : could not resolve host xxxx
```

Comment: Can you use `writeBin` directly without `rawToChar`?

Comment: actually `read.csv %>% textconnection %>% readBin` worked. I am still curious about this difference between packages tho

Comment: Have you tried `paws.storage::s3_download_file`?